# MySQL - How to select distinct rows after order and group?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
post    |   date    |   tags
--------+-----------+-------
post3   |   2016    |   bbb
post1   |   2018    |   aaa
post2   |   2017    |   ccc
post1   |   2018    |   bbb
post3   |   2016    |   aaa
post2   |   2017    |   bbb
post2   |   2017    |   bbb
post1   |   2018    |   ccc
post3   |   2016    |   ccc
```

And I want get the following result:

```
post    |   date    |   tags
------- +---------- +--------
post1   |   2018    |   aaa
post2   |   2017    |   bbb
post3   |   2016    |   ccc
```

In other words, what I want to do is: Firstly, order the table based on a column (which in this case is the date column). And, secondly, to group according to another column (which in this case is the column tag). And I want, finally, that the result of the post column not be repeated.

The first and second part I know how to do. I apply the query below...

```
SELECT post, `date`, tag
FROM tabela AS t1
WHERE t1.`date` = (
    SELECT MAX(t2.`date`) 
    FROM tabela AS t2 
    WHERE t1.tag = t2.tag
)
```

... and I get the following result:

```
post    |   data    |   tags
------- +---------- +--------
post1   |   2018    |   aaa
post1   |   2018    |   bbb
post1   |   2018    |   ccc
```

The problem, as you can see, is that post1 is repeated for all tags. And I do not want that to happen. I want all rows to be filled intelligently based on the highest value given by the date column but no repeating in the post column.

How can I do this?

PS: Sorry for english errors, I'm not american.

Comment: I added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. This type of question is asked frequently on Stack Overflow. I suggest you follow the tag and look at some of the other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL versions prior to v8x you can use variables like so:

```
SELECT
      post, `date`, tags
FROM (
    SELECT
          @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=t.tags, @row_num + 1, 1) AS RowNumber
        , t.post
        , t.`date`
        , t.tags
        , @prev_value := t.tags
    FROM mytable t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :='') vars
    ORDER BY
          t.tags
          , t.`date` DESC
    ) d
WHERE RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY
      tags, `date`
;

+----+-------+------+------+
|    | post  | date | tags |
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 | post1 | 2018 | aaa  |
|  2 | post1 | 2018 | bbb  |
|  3 | post1 | 2018 | ccc  |
+----+-------+------+------+
```

see: http://rextester.com/HXQ91572

For more recent versions of MySQL or variants like MariaDb, you can simply use `row_number() over()`like this:

```
SELECT
      post, `date`, tags
FROM (
    SELECT
          t.post
        , t.`date`
        , t.tags
        , row_number() over(partition by t.tags order by t.`date`DESC) as RowNumber
    FROM table1 t
    ) d
WHERE RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY
      tags, `date`
;
```

In both query variants above you are computing a value of 1 for each "first row" based on an ordering of the data. Once the wanted row reference is known you can then filter out any unwanted rows.

Comment: Works for my simple example above, but, for a big table, unfortunately, not... :(((

Comment: My answer has been edited. I was using the wrong column to order by, should have been tags & date (initially I used post & date)